# EAV vs Document DB vs XML Column for a system with arbitrary entities?

Tags: mysql, xml, entity-attribute-value, database, nosql

Despite reading an awful lot of varying opinions and advice online and in SO I still cannot really decide the best solution to solve my current requirements.

In essence I need to make a system where objects can be arbitarily defined with any number of properties. The applicaiton tracks the where abouts and state of these objects and I cannot possibly know at compile time what the full gambit of these objects will be (besides this will be sold to many companies to track what they will).

The data itself WILL have some forms of relation to each other. The biggest of which will be the notion of a location hierarchy; think Country->Province->Town->Postcode->Building->Room->Locker->Object

There will be some other Parent->Child relations  in the data too. For example an instance of a car has an instance of an engine, has an instance of a piston.

The history of objects and data will be important. What the state of the object has been at various times and places will be a heavily used feature of this system. Being able to retrieve the full history for reporting will be important too.

The options as I see them:

**EAV - Entity Attribute Value (or hybrid of) in SQL**

Pros:

- It's relational and normalised
- Querying is powerful
- The relational and hierarchical parts of the data fit this paradigm
- History achieved by storing dates against properties

Cons:

- Query complexity
- 90% of the time every attribute for an object will be required giving
  a serious number of joins
- Most likely there will be pivots everywhere
- Others?

**Relational with XML catch all columns:**

Pros:

- Relational goodness, ORMs etc, etc (all of above)
- How to store the history?

Cons:

- The vast majority of the attributes will be in this XML column
  (say>70%)
- Slow queries?
- Others?

**Document DB**

Pros:

- Open Schema
- History is as simple as retrieving older docs

Cons:

- I've got a fair amount of relational data!
- Query support (I'm not well enough versed to say what the pros and
  cons are of each Document DB tech)
- Others?

As you can tell the most of my experience has come in the form of relational DBs (SQL). Add to that I have already prototyped a similar solution with and EAV/Relational hybrid in SQL and found it an utter pain when things got even remotely complex.

I'm tech agnostic; I have front to back end experience in lots of techs and not adverse to learning anything new.

What are the thoughts on my situation; the long and short of it is each of the above is a valid way to solve the problem but I'm keen to hear what other people think and have experienced so I can try to avoid any costly blind sides.

Comment: Correction: EAV is not relational.  The relational model requires that each column be associated with a single domain.  In EAV the domain of a cell in the value column depends on the value of the corresponding cell in the attribute column.  Fortunately for EAV fans, SQL isn't relational either.